# Recursive Del command does not delete all of the matching wildcard glob

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch program which can delete all files having the same extensions anywhere in my computer location `C:` and on my desktop. But when it does work.

Here is the first bat file I've done but nothing happen after launching.

```
@echo off
del "C:\*.vsdx" /s /q
```

I have programed another one that I've tested:

```
@echo off
del "H:\*.vsdx" /s /q
del "C: \*.vsdx" /s /q
del "F:\*.vsdx" /s /q
del "Desktop:\*.vsdx" /s /q
```

Concerning this program, after running it I noticed that `.vsdx` files in device `H:` and `F:` disappear. But files in the location `C:` and some others that I've created in Documents do not disappear. So I'm asking your help on how to solve this issue.

Summary of problem: I want to write a batch file which can delete all files having the same extension from my computer.

Comment: Surely `Desktop` is already on `C:`? so there should be no need to specifically `del`ete those. BTW, you can only delete file for which you have the required permissions, additionally, to ensure that your command also includes files regardless of their assigned attributes, use the `/A` and `/F` options too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about the fact that desktop is part of C: but the problem is that even if specified C: as the only location, it deletes nothing. But when try with a specific folder with the the name of a specific file, it deletes it. So I'm wondering where the problem is.

Comment: You have a space between the colon and the slash: ```"C: \```.  Also, a colon can only appear after a drive letter.  So ```"Desktop:\``` is invalid.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to correct it and retry

Comment: Grrr!!!! It does work. Here is the command I wrote.

Comment: @echo off del "C:\*vsdx" /a /q /s /f but nothing happens. The files I have created on my desktop are still here and those in the folders Documents and Images as well.

Comment: Excuse me for writing it in the same line. I use my phone to chat and it can't separate @echo off and the del.... line with my phone. But on my computer they are aligned.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a period.  The forum software removes the back slash if you don't quote it correctly.  ```del "C:\*.vsdx" /a /q /s /f```. Just open up a command prompt and run it from root of the C: drive.  That way you can see any error messages.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks